# JSON Serialize DateTime in Web API

Tags: magento2, rest-api, date, webapi

A lot of my Web API interfaces use DateTime return types or parameters as follows.

```
interface TestInterface
{
    /**
     * @param \DateTime $value
     * @return void
     */
    public function setDate(\DateTime $value);

    /**
     * Gets the current date.
     * 
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getDate() : \DateTime;
}
```

When trying to request Web API end-point which has TestInterface[] as return type. I get the following error in Magento 2.

> Each getter must have a doc block. See DateTime::format()

So I assume there is no DateTime-Formatter in Magento 2. I took a look into DataObjectProcessor.php and the ServiceOutputProcessor.php assuming it would be an option to provide a custom formatter when an Object is of type \DateTime.

Any suggestions or solution to this problem? Best would be if my DateTime ojects would end up being [ISO8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) serialized as in JSON standard.

Comment: Filled a [ticket with Magento on GitHub](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/24791). Hope to get it resolved there.